# Photoshop CS5 in Fedora 15

Tags: fedora, samba, kvm, wine

I'm working on a project, which implies that I use photoshop design files. So far I haven't figured out the best way to deal with it in Fedora 15.

I installed GIMP, but layers don't look as they do in Photoshop version (shades, blurs are missing) - are there any improvements for this case? I think additional packages might boost GIMP's rendering.

I tried installing Photoshop CS5 in Wine, but got

> fixme:file:MoveFileWithProgressW MOVEFILE_WRITE_THROUGH unimplemented

And the installer itself told:

> The Setup encountered an error(-1) during install. Please restart the
>   machine and try again.

I think KVM (Windows XP) + SAMBA (in order to save designed stuff on fedora) might work.

What is my best choice in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GIMP doesn't support the full set of features which Photoshop supports; namely, layer effects (blurs, shades etc...) aren't supported, this is why you lose those.

KVM should work, but using VirtualBox is easier, doesn't require Samba configuration (you can just use shared folders) and works equally well.

Wine has problems running recent Photoshop versions (last one that runs well is CS2, if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: It has worked for me. In fact it runs even quicker than on KVM! Thank you so much, you've saved my time!

Comment: Yep. Despite all the hype around Gimp, in many ways it's still less powerful than Photoshop 6.0, which introduced layer styles a dozen years ago.